# How to use class annoted as @Builder in Spring's @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, lombok

I have class annoted with Lombok's @Builder, and I want to have Spring's @Bean that has:

```
return AnnotedClass.builder().build();
```

The question is: how should I use this @Bean to set values for fields by builder?

When I do inside Bean:

```
return AnnotedClass.builder().field1(value1).build();
```

then I can later get setted value, but I want to set value from outside the Bean.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want probably write a false code for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but: You can't to that. The builder is created by a static method in `AnnotatedClass` and get's destroyed after the `build()` call. So when you have the instance of `AnnotatedClass` the builder is gone. And since you are using injection you of course cannot give arbitrary arguments to the bean method.

The builder pattern is meant to create immutable objects with optional fields and injection is meant to wire in services. Which is totally not what you apparently want.

I recommend that you take a look at the factory pattern. Inject a factory (e.g. `AnnotatedClassFactory`) into your class and let that factory build you the instances you need. You can have the factory return an instance of the builder, of course. This would allow you to have injected values that you can preset in each instance of the builder and you can do the rest outside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way

```java
    @Value("${value.from.properties}")
    String beanParam;

    @Bean
    public beanName() {
       return AnnotedClass.builder().firstParameter(beanParam).build();
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure but maybe you can use `@Value` to annotate the bean factory method parameter.

Comment: I ment that I would like inject this Bean and give arguments to injected object, before .build() will take place.

Comment: I guess I'm not 100% sure about what exactly you want to do. Maybe you could provide a more detailed code example or explanation?

Comment: I want to do on injected Bean:
.builder().field1(value1).field2(value2).build();

Comment: Is the number of parameter for concrete Builder is known?